Problem with modal counterpoint
I'm new to counterpoint and this time i tried challenging myself by writing a counterpoint in second species in phrygian E
I'm sure there are problems with my counterpoint and wanted to see if anyone more pro could help me understand them and notice them
I also don't know what to do about the cadence to avoid breaking the rules so i put a  C# to avoid tritone with the F in the upper part
I also didn't use D# afterward because it will make disoonanse with F in the upper part
But the melody would make a minor second stepwise motion that i' not sure i'm premitted to have
https://i.postimg.cc/WbqvdsSp/20240501-161718.jpg

Note, C#-F is a diminished fourth, not a third.

I thought i could use it because the F natural is the enharmonic of E# what do you suggest me to put there?


Yeah, you can spell an interval with a different enharmonic spelling and it can change the number. C to D# is an augmented 2nd; C to Eb is a minor third. But note also, you said "I put a C# to avoid tritone with the F," but a tritone is an augmented 4th, not a diminished one. In other words the C would have been fine; it would only have been a tritone if the F was sharp (or if the F was natural and the C was flat).


As a curiosity, what book are you working through?

That was such an obvious mistake i made . Thank you for that but i don't think the natural C would be fine . I still forms a perfect fourth on the downbeat

@user98606 you are correct that C can not appear in that measure as it forms a perfect fourth.


i put a C# to avoid tritone with the F in the upper part...

Like @nuggethead I though to try A D E (or just D for the whole penultimate bar) as the last three notes of your counterpoint bass. The main idea being the F could be harmonized with either D for a tenth or A for a sixth.

...also didn't use D# afterward because it will make disoonan

For this kind of species counterpoint exercise, the final cadence will be step-wise motion in both voices, in contrary motion, with one of the steps being a half step and the other being a whole step.
In some cases, such as a final cadence in dorian, that means you will use a sharp on the C to D motion, which effectively creates a leading tone.
In phrygian we get a unique case. The half step motion, the motion you can think of as the leading tone motion, will be the F to E descending half step, the other step will be the whole step from D ascending to E.
So, you definitely do not need to use a sharp on D. Also, you can think of the half step of the final cadence in phrygian as a sort of "upside down leading tone."

Now it's so clear to me why we wouldn't use a D# thank you

Start backwards.  What is your last note in the counterpoint?  In the Phrygian mode with the CF on top, D is the only choice.  And against the G in the CF you have E, so begin like this...

Now fill in the two missing beats.  Here is one possible solution:

Another solution is that it is possible to use a whole note in the second-to-last measure.  So this is viable also:

Whatever you do, definitely don't use any accidentals in this stage of counterpoint.  You have to make do with the "white notes."  Also, avoid using the tritone B-F even if they aren't at the same instant.  This example (below) sounds a little wonky because we still hear the B-F tension even though they don't sound at the same time.

All of these peculiarities about the Phrygian mode make life tricky but give it its character.

Thank you it is so easy to understand with the picture .
